# Django - QuerySet - Get the average percentage of field with certain value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have got the following model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    #bunch of fields

class Order(models.Model):
    STATES = ('Successful','In_progress', 'Cancelled', 'Intended')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=11,choices=STATES,default='INTENDED')
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

I need to retrieve the avg of SUCCESSFUL state Orders for each user using only one Django orm query.

Comment: Why only one query? Have you tried anything?

Comment: what is relation between UserProfile and Order?

Comment: it should be possible with django [function F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#aggregate-expressions/)  and  [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the ForeignKey field for the Order Class. I have found a workaround for it already using annotate and conditional expressions.

Comment: it doesn't make sense - average of a non-numeric field  ? i.e. state

Comment: It's the percentage of successful state orders over the total orders of each user. That relationship should return a percentage which would be the average.